# How to store millions of entries in temporary local storage

Tags: java, database, hashmap, runtime

I'm doing a migration job of millions of pieces of data from one database to another. In the first database I have two different tables (which is accessible to me as a text file I download - I don't have access to the database proper) 
(1) Cities - wherein each line is a City object with instance variables separated by tab (e.g. `id     name     population`)

(2) CitiesToTopics - wherein each line is a city id and a corresponding topic (e.g. `id      topic`). This is not unique per line. So, 2 lines can share an id and the means that the corresponding city has 2 topics [topic1, topic2].

In this migration I am going to make a new POJO called City which has

```
public class City {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private long population;
    private List<String> topics;
    // removed getters and setters
}
```

And add these Cities to my new database.

I would like to first query the CitiesToTopics table and get create a

`HashMap<String, List<String>> citiesToTopics` which maps each id -> List[topic].

And then, query the second table, and for each line, take the id and do
`List<String> topics = citiesToTopics.get(id)` and then create `City(id, name, population, topics)`.

This is all fine and good except that there are 26+ million cities and about 150 million entries in CitiesToTopics. As such, I keep getting memory errors or GC errors when I try to run the program. I've upgraded to a [fastutil hashmap](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/objects/Object2ObjectLinkedOpenCustomHashMap.html%20/) but am getting a "A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment". I can't really use an external database to house my temporary citiesToTopics as SQLite can do about 950 inserts/sec which in my case means will take about 2 days to run. Is there a better way to handle this much data especially when it's really just a temporary way of making sure that each City gets its appropriate topics?

Thanks in advance,

**EDIT:** The massaging necessary - which is why I need to create the temporary data structure - is take a line which has `id     topic` in as a String, split the line by `\t` and  put it into the map. Then, take a line which has `id      name     population`, split by `\t`, create a new `JSONObject` which will be {"Id": "97987987", "name": "Boston", "Population": "673,184", "Topics": ["summer", "winter"]}.

Comment: Why do you use java instead of importing the file directly into the database?

Comment: I fail to see the need for any temporary storage or POJOs.

Comment: @assylias I need the temporary storage in order to hold the topics while I  massage the data into the proper format of the new database. The new database will be stored with everything in one place as JSON which is not how it's currently done.

Comment: @LivingRobot what is the new database? What is your target JSON structure?

Comment: @assylias I'm uploading to an S3 bucket and the JSON will look like `{Id: "790789799", "Name": "Boston", "Population": "673,184", "Topics": ["summer", "winter", "spring"] }`

Comment: Why do you get the entire data at once ? Get the data with smaller groups for example from id 1 to 500000, apply the needed process, then release the memory they hold before to start the other group.

Comment: "I can't really use an external database to house my temporary citiesToTopics as SQLite can do about 950 inserts/sec which in my case means will take about 2 days to run" It is a migration task. it will executed once. Why would it be annoying ?

Comment: @ftb ids aren't in the database sorted. So, I don't know how much to read in  in order to run it on the other files.

Comment: To state the obvious, you cannot keep all of that date in memory.  Thus, you will have to use some combination of a streaming approach (by which I don't mean a Java Stream but rather an approach that processes data in batches rather than all at once), and a persistence mechanism.  To understand what would be best requires knowing what massaging you need to do.  Edit your question with this information.

Comment: @SteveBrandii edited with appropriate information. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is:

- sort the two files by id. For example, on linux, you can use something like `cat file | sort -k1 > sorted_file` (not tested) which would probably do the trick in a reasonable amount of time (it will take a few hours on the larger file, but not days)
- Iterate over the cities and the topics files once in a synchronized manner, now that you know all records are sorted, and populate your new DB in batches of N cities. You won't need more memory than the size of the batch.

Comment: This was a really good idea and I ended up doing a variant on it. Because I have 46 city-to-topic files and 19 city files (not just 2 big ones) I ended up going through each file (both , and for each city take `id % 100` and put the city into a new file called `city_(id % 100).txt` or `city_to_topic_(id % 100).txt` so that I have a natural batching process so that I can run things in parallel easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@assylias is right: sort Cities file by id, then citiesToTopics by city id as well. Main point is to have those files sorted. In that case you do not need to pull whole files into memory or anywhere else before processing and your program will use very few memory no more than one object in new structure and only one line from each file.

As example your program can have two nested loops (in pseudo code):

```
nextCityToTopic = CityToTopicsFile.readFirstLine
for each city in citiesFile {
       city = citiesFile.readNextLine
       newJsonStructure = createNewforCity
       curCityId = city.id
       do {              
         if nextCityToTopic.cityId == nextCityToTopic.cityId {
              add Topic into newJsonStructure 
              nextCityToTopic = CityToTopicsFile.readNextLine
         } else {
            insert newJsonStructure into database
            break
         }             
       } while CityToTopicsFile.hasMoreLines
}
```

P.S. In real it is a comment to @assylias post.  Sorry it is quite large - so I just added as an answer.